# How to restrict branch creation based on pattern in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, branch, bitbucket-server, configuration-management

I am using Atlassian Bitbucket server v4.8.6.

How do I restrict restrict branch creation based on pattern.

Rules explained below -

1. Only ABC team should be able to create release/ABC-*
2. Only XYZ team should be able to create personal/XYZ-*

Answer (score 3):

You can't create rules to prevent only the "creation" of branches. These are the avaliable restrictions:

```
Prevent all changes
Prevent deletion
Prevent rewriting history
Prevent changes without a pull request
```

To create branch permissions do the following:

1. Go to Repository > Settings > Branch permissions > Add permissions
2. Select "Branch pattern"
3. Add branch pattern, ex: release/ABC-*
4. Select one of the restrictions available
5. Add the group exception, ex: ABC

Answer (score -4):

This can be done by adding "*" on *Select branch* text field. See the screenshot below.

1. Go to your repository > Settings > Branch permissions > Add permission
2. Under "Select branch - By name or pattern", put an asterisk (*)
3. Save

[image: Add a branch permission]

After that, you can restrict each branch patterns you want for different teams or people.

ABC group

1. Select branch = release/ABC-*
2. Write access = ABC group or ABC members

Personal branch

1. Select branch = personal/XYZ-*
2. Write Access = Your account

Comment: Branch pattern '*' overlaps all other branches too

Comment: this does not work. the * restricts everything, you cant then unrestrict things under that.

I want to make sure nobody can make a branch thats not in a folder (ie, feature/xyz is allowed but xyz in the "root")

Also would like to make sure a feature/ branch has to start with a jira ticket number, but thats not possible either...